# React child component using layered map methods on layered objects and arrays does not re-render when sub array is updated

Tags: reactjs

I have a component I am working on where the parent passes in a particular prop from its state. The prop is an array where each element of the array contains sub object that contains its own array.

```
import react, {useState} from 'react';
import Posts from './Posts';

function App() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([
    {title: 'post1',data:{comments:['comment1', 'comment2','comment3']}},
    {title: 'post1',data:{comments:['comment1', 'comment2','comment3']}},
    {title: 'post1',data:{comments:['comment1', 'comment2','comment3']}},
  ])

  const deleteComment = (postIndex, commentIndex) =>{
    let newPosts = [...posts];
    newPosts[postIndex].comments.splice(commentIndex, 1);
    setPosts(newPosts);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Parent Component</h1>
      <Posts posts={posts} deleteComment={deleteComment}  />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This prop gets passed down to a child component that then also receives a delete Comment Function. When that function is fired, the comment is deleted from state. However, when the props are updated, the child component does not re-render. My understanding is that React only looks at the top array and its top level elements to note if it re-renders, and does not catch a change at this depth in the object. What is the best way to make my child component re-render when the delete comment function is fired?

import React from 'react'

```
export default function Posts({posts, deleteComment}) {
    console.log('posts: ', posts)
  return (
    <>
    <h2>Posts</h2>
    {posts.map((post, postIndex)=>{
        return(
            <div key={post.title}>
            <h3>{post.title}</h3>
            {post.data.comments.map((comment, commentIndex)=>{
                return(<><p>{comment}</p> 
                <button onClick={()=>{deleteComment(postIndex,commentIndex)}}>Delete</button></>)
                
            })}
            </div>)}
        )
        
    })
    </>
    
  )
}
```

I should also note this is a simplified example of something I'm working on for an employer, so taking comments out of data, and putting it in each post is not doable in the project I'm working on.

Comment: use newPosts[postIndex].data.comments.splice not newPosts[postIndex].comments.splice

Comment: when you are rendering based on an array or objects or sth like this, you should always have a `key` in every item that gets rendered

Comment: Thanks, I added in a key to the second map method, however that doesn't seem to solve the re-rendering issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you missed the data prop. try this :

```js
  const deleteComment = (postIndex, commentIndex) =>{
    let newPosts = [...posts];
    newPosts[postIndex].data.comments.splice(commentIndex, 1);
    setPosts(newPosts);
  }
```

it is also advisable to use filter which is not mutate the old state and it is always create new array

Answer (score 1):

`Array.splice` mutates the array itself instead of creating a new one. When you call `setState` you're passing in the same array reference so a change is not detected. Use `.filter` instead and set a new array to state.